# How to exclude some of the projects building from parallel build?

Tags: maven, concurrency

I am using TDD and have many modules with end to end tests.

Some of them are starting a server on the same port, so I can't make them parallel.

How can I mark some artifacts not to run in parallel?

Comment: As @glitch noted below *(cit) "The parallel build feature of Maven ... if ... then Module B will always build **after** Module A."* which is a degree of freedom a true-`[PARALLEL]`-process has not. This means that Maven builds under a "just"-`[CONCURRENT]` scheduling strategy ( as dependency-graph permits, moving parts to a `[SERIAL]`-build sequence ( again a step common in a "just"-`[CONCURRENT]` but **not in a true `[PARALLEL]`-scheduling**, even if all Maven promoters, enthusiasts and/or blindsighted freaks call it parallel or parallel^2 ). **Never call an "odd" number "even". Yes, Never**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few options:

1. The parallel build feature of Maven is 'dependency aware' so if Module B depends on Module A then Module B will always build after Module A. This supercedes the parallel build instruction. So, you could add a dependency to force serial builds. But, yeah, that's contrived and could get awkward.
2. Split your build into sub groups of modules which can be safely run in parallel and then run the `mvn` command for each of these sub groups using `-pl` to instruct Maven to build each sub group ...

> ```
> -pl,--projects <arg>                Comma-delimited list of specified
>                                     reactor projects to build instead
>                                     of all projects. A project can be
>                                     specified by [groupId]:artifactId
>                                     or by its relative path.
> ```

3. Define profiles to create the logical sub groups so that if Module A and Module C belong in a sub group named, say, "Foo" then these sub modules would be activated by `-PFoo`.
4. (Possibly) Rework your tests such that they can be safely parallelised. You've probably already considered this so I'm only including it here for complteness.

Note: options `2` and `3` are effectively the same, they are just two different ways of defining logical 'parallelable' sub groups within your parent project.